# Finish this sequence of figures

Tags: sequence

So I know the position of the square. I am stuck with the colors and I do not understand the position of the two smaller rhombuses.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind letting us know where you got this from, as it appears to not be your own creation?

Comment: It's from an IQ-test.

Comment: I think you need to specify what IQ test, is it online test? if yes then you should put a source link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> B, second image from the top

because

> The square pattern is moved 3 steps around the sides clockwise. Then the white pattern is always in the third row. So the only answer that matches the square pattern and the white pattern is B. I'm still working for the other shape's pattern.
>
>  **update**:
>  From the answer, I guess the rhombuses' patterns are one of them moves down one step, and one of them is moved around the sides one step counter clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> The second one?

Because

> The bottom row is always white, and the top 2 rows are always black, so it must be either the first or the second one

And

> You know the position of the square by rotating the previous square 90 degrees and moving it forward by 1.